# MySQL: Finding the nearest date in past or future

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, datediff

The subquery below will return the nearest date in the past, I'm wanting to adapt this so it finds the nearest date in past or future.

```
SELECT date,

    (SELECT value
     FROM `users check-ins` as c
     WHERE c.date < p.date AND `userid` = '$userid'
     ORDER BY c.date DESC
     LIMIT 1) as weight

FROM `users photos` as p
WHERE `userid` = '$userid'
ORDER BY date ASC
```

I've read about the `ABS` and `DATEDIFF` functions but cannot get them working how I imagined:

```
SELECT date,

    (SELECT value
     FROM `users check-ins` as c
     WHERE `userid` = '$userid'
     ORDER BY ABS(DATEDIFF(c.date, p.date)) DESC
     LIMIT 1) as weight

FROM `users photos` as p
WHERE `userid` = '$userid'
ORDER BY DATE ASC
```

So the subquery should return `value` from the row that is closest to `p.date`

**EDIT:**

Here's an [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/64869/1/0).

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET

Comment: Add `ABS(DATEDIFF(c.date, p.date))` as one of the values to be returned temporarily perhaps?  So you can actually see what is happening?

Comment: I've added an SQLFiddle.

Comment: @Zoredache it's returning differently, yes. But unsure how to use it to grab the 'value'

Answer (score 0):

You need to order by `asc` not `desc` in the subquery:

```
SELECT date,

    (SELECT value
     FROM `users check-ins` as c
     WHERE `userid` = '$userid'
     ORDER BY ABS(DATEDIFF(c.date, p.date)) ASC
     LIMIT 1) as weight

FROM `users photos` as p
WHERE `userid` = '$userid'
ORDER BY DATE ASC
```